# Django : downloading a file (pdf version or odt version) through radio buttons

Tags: django, forms, download, radio-button

I trying to propose to the users of my site to download a document in either pdf or odt version through radio buttons. How can I get and use the value of the radio button chosen by the user to serve the appropriate file. So far, I can only serve one at a time.

My current work:

models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf_version = models.FileField()
    odt_version = models.FileField()

def __str__(self):
    '''String name represents class File'''
    return self.name
```

urls.py

```
path('files_page/', views.files_page, name='files_page'),
path('download_file/<int:file_id>/', views.download_file, name='download_file'),
```

views.py

```
def files_page(request):
    files = File.objects.all()
    context = {'files':files}
    return render (request, 'walk/files_page.html', context)


def download_file(request, file_id):
    #No post request; do nothing
    if request.method != 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        #fetch the file to download
        #file = File.objects.get(id=file_id)
        response = FileResponse(open('/home/me/Desktop/super/media_cdn/tog.pdf', 'rb'))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="tog.pdf"'
        return response
```

template

{%block content%}

```
{%for file in files %}
<p>{{file.name}}</p>
<p>{{file.pdf_version}}</p>
<p>{{file.csv_version}}</p>
<form action="{%url 'walk:download_file' file.id%}" method="POST">
{%csrf_token%}
<input type="radio" name="format" value="pdf" checked> pdf
<input type="radio" name="format" value="csv"> csv
<button name="submit">download</button>
</form>
{%endfor%}
{%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with [using forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/). Yes, you use django forms in django instead re-implementing everything yourself.

Create `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

FILE_FORMAT_CHOICES = [("csv", "Download PDF"), ("csv", "Download CSV")]

class FileFormatForm(forms.Form):
    file_format = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FILE_FORMAT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Inside of the template used by `files_page` (just let django render the fields, don't do it yourself):

```
<form action="{%url 'walk:download_file' file.id%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

And finally adjust the `views.py`:

```
def files_page(request):
    ...
    context = {
        'files': files,
        'form': FileFormatForm()  # empty / without POST
    }
    ...


def download_file(request, file_id):
    assert request.method == 'POST', "users should only come here with POST now"
    form = FileFormatForm(request.POST)  # populate from POST
    if form.data['file_format'] == 'pdf':
        return "return PDF file response here"
    else:
        return "return CSV file response here"
```

Note: you don't use `tab` in Python. Use 4x whitespaces instead.

Another Note: [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/) to further reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Comment: if should be 'if form.data['file_format']=='pdf':' instead of 'if form.file_format=='pdf':'. Anyway thank you bro!

Comment: @joseph on stackoverflow: you don't say "thanks", you accept or/and upvote; you don't say "it should be", you're just edit the post to fix it :]